# How to map bought building assets into other objects

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes, procedural, linked-data

I am making a city environment and have purchased a pack of buildings from a 3D asset store.

I have the environment mapped out as primitive objects and am hoping to combine the two with some degree of automation in order not to a) manually place a billion buildings, b) be able to edit pieces and have them update across the environment and c) not have to manually move hundreds of pieces if the environment needs to be changed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started? I know about sharing data across multiple objects and have dipped my toes into geometry nodes, creating groups of simple city buildings on a plane. I think I need to chop the assets I’ve bought into pieces (walls, roofs, roads, street scenery, signs, etc) and work out how to map them into the surfaces of my environment with some kind of logic.

I’m not expecting a set of instructions but if anyone can point me in the direction to get myself started that would be much appreciated.

Thanks
J

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the environment so we can see roughly what this is about?